# placing a camera in a sphere to have the space effect

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xna

i want to as the title says , place a camera IN a sphere, which i created in Autodesk as a 2 faced material with stars, and place that sphere in the world in Visual studio and place a camera inside it. The natural way to do this would be to take the sphere put it in vector.zero, and put the camera at vector. zero as well with the view at any direction. But once the camera gets inside my sphere i cannot see anything.. just the backround.. here is the code any help is appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace _3dGame
{

    public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
    {
        GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
        GameObject starBubble; // represents the outter star texture
        Camera gameCamera;//represents the camera.
        SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

        public Game1()
        {
            graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
            Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        }


        protected override void Initialize()
        {

            starBubble = new GameObject();
            gameCamera = new Camera();
            base.Initialize();
        }


        Model myModel;

        // The aspect ratio determines how to scale 3d to 2d projection.
        float aspectRatio;

        protected override void LoadContent()
        {
            // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
            spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);

            myModel = Content.Load<Model>("Models\\star_bubble2");
            aspectRatio = graphics.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio; 
        }


        protected override void UnloadContent()
        {

        }


        protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            // Allows the game to exit
            if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back ==
                ButtonState.Pressed)
                this.Exit();

            modelRotation += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalMilliseconds *
                MathHelper.ToRadians(0.1f);

            base.Update(gameTime);
        }


        /// <param name="gameTime">Provides a snapshot of timing values.</param>
        // Set the position of the model in world space, and set the rotation.
        Vector3 modelPosition = Vector3.Zero;
        float modelRotation = 0.0f;

        // Set the position of the camera in world space, for our view matrix.
        Vector3 cameraPosition = new Vector3(0,0,0);

        protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
        {
            graphics.GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.White);

            // Copy any parent transforms.
            Matrix[] transforms = new Matrix[myModel.Bones.Count];
            myModel.CopyAbsoluteBoneTransformsTo(transforms);

            // Draw the model. A model can have multiple meshes, so loop.
            foreach (ModelMesh mesh in myModel.Meshes)
            {
                // This is where the mesh orientation is set, as well 
                // as our camera and projection.
                foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
                {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.World = transforms[mesh.ParentBone.Index] *
                        Matrix.CreateRotationY(modelRotation)
                        * Matrix.CreateTranslation(modelPosition);
                    effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition,
                        Vector3.Zero, Vector3.Up);
                    effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
                        MathHelper.ToRadians(45.0f), aspectRatio,
                        1.0f, 10000.0f);
                }
                // Draw the mesh, using the effects set above.
                mesh.Draw();
            }
            base.Draw(gameTime);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I say this without knowing the framework you're using, but you might be getting bitten by [Back-Face Culling](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Back_face_culling).  If you can see the sphere from the outside, but not from the inside, that's almost certainly what's going on, and you'll want to turn it off when drawing the sphere (but leave it on for everything else, as it increases performance).  Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you after a lot of searching i found the way to do this and you were right!:) thank you very very very much, u can add this as an answer to thumb you up.

Answer (score 2):

(Indeed: fixing the Normals is important)

Extra tips:

Do not rotate the Sphere with the camera.

Draw the Sphere first while z buffer is switched off.

[See this article](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/XNA/Csharp/Series2/Skybox.php) (it uses a skybox but that is not important here)